# How to start a Snakemake workflow on AWS and detach?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snakemake, tibanna

I am trying to execute a Snakemake workflow on AWS, and have succeeded in executing my workflow using the command:

```
snakemake --tibanna --use-conda --default-remote-prefix=mybucket/myproject
```

and it works successfully. So far, so good. Unfortunately `snakemake` keeps running in the foreground in the terminal until the workflow ends. Using Ctrl-C on it ends the run. This is problematic for me when I want to run a pipeline that takes a few days.

Is there a way to run pipelines using `snakemake --tibanna` and detach and poll the results later?

I believe `tibanna` has the capability: `tibanna run_workflow` runs the workflow and detatches, and you can check the status later using `tibanna stat`. I just can't get `snakemake` to finish leaving the processes scheduled in the cloud.

Comment: Have you tried using `nohup` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Use)?

Comment: It doesn’t cover what I want. I want to trigger the computation in the cloud and shut down my computer, not keep the process working in the background.